# Url Rewrite In form

Tags: php, html

I have a form with post method. I am leaving the action field blank. So on submitting it should redirect to the same page.

But I have action like

> page.php?id=1

when I submit the form it removes the query string from URL so i am not able to get it via $_GET method.

So how i can get id param as well. Its working fine on local but having issue on the live server.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a hidden input in your HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" />
```